# WFFM form through FXM

Tags: wffm, fxm

I am trying to place a WFFM form on 3rd party(HTML) site using FXM. The form is getting rendered successfully on 3rd party site. However, the form submission is not working properly. Upon submit, it is being redirected to the beacon URL(`.../sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/...`), which is resulting some JSON.

Also it is posting to `/sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Tracking.aspx` (For validations and etc) on 3rd party site and is returning a 404.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Did you select the MVC Form rendering?  I don't think the Form rendering, which is for Web Forms, is supported for use with FXM.

Comment: Thanks @BenGolden. Using MVC rendering solved the problem.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to use the MVC Form rendering rather than the Web Forms version, which is just named Form.  The Web Forms version of the rendering is not supported for use with FXM.  See the documentation: [Add an MVC form to an external website with FXM](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/using_web_forms/creating_web_forms/add_an_mvc_form_to_an_external_website_with_fxm)